# I need black bars on the left and right sides Corona sdk for Android

Tags: android, lua, coronasdk

How a can make game with not all screen in horizontal orientation? I need black bars on the left and right sides like on the picture.

my config.lua

```
application =
```

{
content =
{
width = 320,
height = 480,
scale = "letterbox",
fps = 60,

```
    --[[
    imageSuffix =
    {
            ["@2x"] = 2,
            ["@4x"] = 4,
    },
    --]]
},
```

}

build.settings

```
orientation =
{
    -- Supported values for orientation:
    -- portrait, portraitUpsideDown, landscapeLeft, landscapeRight
    default = "landscapeRight",
    supported = { "landscapeLeft", "landscapeRight", },
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: it would be helpful to know how you setup the rest of the screen. how is the black border defined? fixed width? or does it depend on the resolution available? you should provide more information. There are many ways to make a black border. the simplest ist to draw black rectangles.

Comment: Thanks. I added new information to my question. Yes i tryed draw rectangles but i cant get real height of the topbar. Some phones have only front camera on display, some phones have notches (like iphones X). And i need black border on this place. I hope you understand my english:)